# How to use Google Charts with Vue.js library?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to make a Chart with Google Charts using Vue.js library, but I don't know how to add to the div.

Here what I'm had tried to do, this is how to add a chart with vanilla javascript ([Here the code example of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start)), I tried to adapt to vue, but nothing happenned:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});

Vue.component('line-char', {
    data: function(){
        // Create the data table.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Tiempo', 'Temperatura'],
            [1,  1000],
            [2,  1170],
            [3,  660],
            [4,  1030]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {
            'title': 'Data Line',
            'width': '100%',
            'height': 250,
            legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    },
    template: '<div v-model="chart_div"></div>'
});
```

html:

```
<div id="component">
    <line-chart></line-chart>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you'll want to do is use a `ref` for your `<div>` and then register a callback to draw the chart in your component's `mounted` hook.

```js
// Load library
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']})

const lineChartOptions = {
  title: 'Data Line',
  width: '100%',
  height: 250,
  legend: { position: 'bottom' }
}

Vue.component('LineChart', {
  template: `<div ref="chart"></div>`, //  set ref here
  data: () => ({
    headings: ['Tiempo', 'Temperatura'],
    chartData: [
      [1,  1000],
      [2,  1170],
      [3,  660],
      [4,  1030]
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    drawChart () {
      const dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        this.headings,
        ...this.chartData
      ], false) //  don't forget "false" here to indicate the first row as labels

      const chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(this.$refs.chart) //  use ref here
      chart.draw(dataTable, lineChartOptions)
    }
  }
  mounted () {
    // set the library loaded callback here
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(() => this.drawChart())    
  }
})
```

---

As mentioned by [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/184499/matt), if your component's template is truly empty save for a single `<div>`, you can use the `$el` property to mount the chart without bothering with refs

```js
Vue.component('LineChart', {
  template: `<div></div>`,
  // ...
  methods: {
    drawChart () {
      // ...
      const chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(this.$el)
      chart.draw(this.dataTable, options)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: +upvote though in this case I would probably go for `this.$el` instead of a ref.

Comment: @Matt sure, if there's nothing else in the template, that would be fine too.

Comment: @Phil Thanks, but I get another error: `Cannot read property 'LineChart' of undefined`, apparently, google.charts is not correctly defined. how did you define `google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});`.?

Comment: @DrakoPD I assumed you had all that sorted out. I'll update my answer

Comment: @Phil, Thanks now is working.  I had something, but apparently, my method didn't worked. What was wrong with your past code?

Comment: @DrakoPD It didn't have the `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback()` which you need to wait for before you can use anything from `google.visualization`. I had assumed you already had that somewhere else in your code

Comment: @Phil I supposed that the error of `undefined` was about the google.charts need time to load complete, so I was tried different methods to give it time. But I forgot `.setOnLoadCallback()` because I assumed that the draw function was called automatically.

Answer (score 1):

#### As per an update this solution is no longer advisable

A more simple usage would be to use the `vue-google-charts` [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-charts#usage)

Example code:

```
  <GChart
    type="ColumnChart"
    :data="chartData"
    :options="chartOptions"
  />
```

```
 chartData: [
            ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
            ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
            ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
            ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
            ['2017', 1030, 540, 350],
        ],
        chartOptions: {
            chart: {
                title: 'Company Performance',
                subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
            },
        },
```

Comment: `vue-google-charts` seems to be abandoned since 2020. i have a major production issues on responsive feature but no solution works. i have to move away from this and find an alternative

Comment: Thank you for letting me know @MahanHazratiSagharchi. I am using it in production.

Comment: I see a reference to puppeteer-core in the package-json of vue-google-charts. That is a head-less chrome. I am not sure how the pnpm reference comes in to play, but it is disturbing in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

wrapper.innerHTML would let you customize the tooltip to be responsive just make sure the DOM is unique, things are properly destroyed to render on the correct component

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).