# Cannot get vue-google-charts to work in browser mode

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-visualization

I'm starting to learn `Vue.js` and can use Google Charts standalone but cannot get the `vue-google-charts` component to work. I've included both `vue.js` and `vue-google-charts.js` as per instructions here https://github.com/devstark-com/vue-google-charts#browser but the chart does not render and get I the following error message

```
Unknown custom element: <gchart>
```

Example can be viewed here https://jsfiddle.net/ugLc0zrj/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62566146/12511801) might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In console you can see this error:

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://raw.githubusercontent.com/devstark-com/vue-google-charts/master/dist/vue-google-charts.browser.js with MIME type text/plain. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

The script wasn't loaded. Other people had similar issues using `raw.githubusercontent.com`: [Github issue- i couldn't use the component directly on browser](https://github.com/devstark-com/vue-google-charts/issues/24)

Use this CDN link suggested by authors instead: `https://unpkg.com/vue-google-charts@0.3.3/dist/vue-google-charts.browser.js`

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/7n69x5ga/15/)

Comment: Thanks, locally I'm not using external URLs and get the same error. However, I see you added a `template` property which seems to make all the difference! I would love to understand why this is needed, but either way you are a legend.

Comment: @drjeep because if you put it directly inside HTML, the browser will process it, and it doesn't know what is `<GChart>` element, it needs to be processed and resulting HTML should be added to DOM by `Vue.js`, let me know if it is clear, or i can try to rephrase it
`